What's wrong with my bread maker?
I'm not sure if that's a place I can ask this question. I've got a 10 years old bread maker, that I've used about 50 times.
2 weeks ago, upon turning it on, everything looked and sounded usual (screen turns on with parameters displays, machine emits a beep, and LED turns on), but pressing ANY button wouldn't do anything (would normally emit a beep and change parameters on the display).
I found that very odd that all buttons would stop functioning at the same time (as in, does not look like a mechanical fault). I contacted the manufacturer who was nice enough to send me the schematics.

Looks it's using something like a scan matrix. I checked the “input” side of switches, they get regular pulses. I then put a micrograbber on the µC legs (PB5), and when pressing the “CANCEL” and “MODIFY” buttons, the oscilloscope got the same pulses.
Edit: checking the "input" side means I probed their side connected to PA6, PA7 and PB1. They get pulses. PB2..PB5 are flat until buttons are pressed.
To me, that validates that the buttons part of the circuit functions correctly. Am I right?
The microchip power source is at 4.8 V, within the range in the datasheet.
Reset button didn't do anything for the problem (but it resets).
Playing a bit with it, I also get the whole thing to beep and display error codes.
I probed the crystal legs on the µC, one gave a beautiful sine wave at 4 MHz, however the other one gave me this:

It's not impossible my probes were not well-placed. Probing some solder blobs that I suspected would be the crystal gave me 32.77 kHz, so it leads me to believe the crystal is fine.
Now, assuming both crystals are oscillating properly, the chip should have a proper time base. Also corroborated by the fact the “scan pulses” are very well-timed (in frequency, I can't know their expected duration).
The input from buttons on the µC pins is what I'd expect it to be.
The µC controls the LCD properly.
At that point, I mostly suspect something is wrong with the µC itself. Does that sound like a fair assessment?

the problem may be that one of the buttons is stuck down

place [to] ask this question see Electrical Engineering@SE topics: consumer appliances are off topic with the exception of repurposing. Repair of major appliances is explicitly on-topic with Home Improvement @SE.

continuous keyboard scan is overrated,  drive all the columns and read all the rows and wait for something to change.  then scan.

check the keyboard outputs (PA6 PA7 PB1)  are they going high (all at the same time or one at a time doesn't matter)   check the inputs (PB2 PB3 PB4 PB5) - do they stay low unless you press a button

what does the datasheet say about the flash retention time of this microcontroller?

@JasenСлаваУкраїні Not sure I had checked PB2..PB5 independently for the theory of button stuck, thank you. Done now, all are low when no button pressed.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні interesting suggestion about retention. It's got an EPROM, I'm wondering if it's an EPROM or actually EEPROM. So far haven't found any info in the datasheet, just an SE question about EPROM retention, whose answer suggests... 10 years.

@greybeard Thanks for the comment! However (and I might be wrong) I don't feel like a 100 USD bread maker is a major appliance. Also in the meantime I found the "repair" tag that states: "Questions relating to electrical/electronic repair. Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired." Made me feel more that EE SE was the right place.

Is the temperature sensor working properly? The software may be waiting for something, that never happens.

@Jens Not sure, but, some attempts lead to the board beeping so it seems "alive", or the board turning from its standard display to an error code. Also at some point, rather than having it fed through 230V, I did feed 5V directly. Board was "not happy" (when powered up, LED would turn on, I'd get its usual beep, but LCD would stay black and within 1s, I get a permanent beep which stops when I power off). But thanks, I'll see about checking it.

@jsotola is on the right track. The least reliable part of the device probably is the user input: membrane switch, pushbuttons or somesuch. How do you tell it what to do? A user manual would help.

@stretch I'm not sure I understand. The "buttons" are common "tactile switches". They have all been individually tested (none of them makes unwanted contact), and if one of them was to make unwanted contact, then the pulses emitted on PA6, PA7 and PB1 should be read on PB2..5. These 4 have external pulldowns (R11..13, R20), and I've verified for each of them with oscilloscope, when not interacting with the tactile switches, PB2..5 are ~0V.

@stretch However in case it'd be useful, there's a link to the manual: https://sunbeam-app-staging.s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/BM4500_20EM1_%28ANZ%29_ba9fcb7d27.pdf

I was thinking of a switch not making contact rather than stuck on, but your tests have ruled out both faults.
